# Receiving an error while editing permissions of the objects in the bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud

I am receiving below error while trying to edit the permissions of the objects in my bucket

Cannot get legacy ACL for an object when uniform bucket-level access is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have selected access control as uniform, you can change it to fine-grained, if you want to add permissions in object level.

To do this you can click on the 3 buttons present on the right of your bucket - click on edit bucket permissions - select switch to fine-grained under access control - select fine grained - click save.